# Plese help me. Matlab 'while' loop. A set of data is given

Tags: function, while-loop

Now I calculate the value of F from equation. From the F that I determined, I need to find the diameter from set of data.

THe method is like this. If my F value is smaller than the value of F from the data, then I choose the corresponding diameter.

For example. The value of F that I calculated is 11. The value of F from the data is 8, 10, 12, 14, 16. The first value is 8, final value is 16, and its corresponding diameter is 1,2,3,4,5.

11 is bigger than 8, the first value of the data, hence we move to the next F on the data. Again, 11 is bigger 10, we move to the next F.

But 11 is less than 12, the iteration is stop. We need not look further. We take the diameter of 12, which is 3.

You get the idea.

And for the set of data. Here's  the code. The while (Fa==0) function is the condition that I apply in order to perform this question.

```
while Fa==0
load data.dat;
diameter=data(:,1);
F=data(:,2);
```

I'm stuck at that.

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I understand your problem: You have a dataset from which you get a list of values `F`. Now you also calculate a single value `Fc`, and you want to find the element `Fe` in the list, which satisfies the two conditions

- closest to `Fc`
- `Fc < Fe`

One way to achieve this is by the following

```
F  = [1 2 3 4.5 5 6 7 8];
Fc = 4;

sort(F);
for i=1:length(F)
    if(Fc<F(i))
        Fe = F(i);
        break
    end
end
```

This gives 4.5. From this value of `Fe` you can find the desired diameter.